# Object/FieldPermissions objects have field SObjectType, how can values be greater than 40 characters?

Tags: bulk-api, replication

I am currently in the process of working on a replication application to pull data down from Salesforce via the Bulk API and push data into an Enterprise Data Warehouse. The schema is pulled for objects first and then the tables are populated. Currently I am running into an issue on both the ObjectPermissions and FieldPermissions objects as the field SObjectType is defined with a length of 40 characters. However, it seems that this is a soft length when used in conjunction with a namespace. We currently have BMC Remedyforce installed and they have created the following table: BMCServiceDesk__CommunicationEndpoint__c which is greater than 40 characters with the namespace and less than 40 characters without the namespace.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Has anyone seen this before and come up with a workaround for defining a schema where the length does not represent a hard limit?
2. Is there any documentation to support that this is expected behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: 40 Characters not including namespace. There is also a bug in the tooling api when a validation rule name is 80 characters and it has a namespace, salesforce chokes. So yes, 40 characters without the namespace

Comment: But yet the values include the namespace. So when we pull the schema we create a column 40 characters wide and then our replication chokes because we try to insert values that are too large.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and you are seeing correct behavior. Namespaces can be up to 15 characters so you may have to adjust accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

40 Characters not including namespace. There is also a bug in the tooling api when a validation rule name is 80 characters and it has a namespace, salesforce chokes. So yes, 40 characters without the namespace

I understand what you are saying and you are seeing correct behavior. Namespaces can be up to 15 characters so you may have to adjust accordingly